# Unity 3d new input system how to get action binding name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to know what is the name of the binding calling my function. But within the `InputAction.CallbackContext` variable, this information is missing.

[image]

Here is how I do:

```
private void OnDisable()
{
    movingBinds.PlayerMovingMap.Moves.performed -= ctx => MoveIt(ctx);
    
}

private void MoveIt(InputAction.CallbackContext ctx)
{
    Debug.Log(ctx);
}
```

The console output for the context variable when A is pressed (binding name `Left`):

```
{ action=PlayerMovingMap/Moves[/Keyboard/w,/Keyboard/s,/Keyboard/a,/Keyboard/d] phase=Performed time=5,94887570000014 control=Key:/Keyboard/a value=(0,0, -1,0) interaction= }
```

I have the key pressed, the Vecto2 value, but not the binding name. But I need it because if the player decide to change his key for `Left`, I'd got scr*wed.

How can I get the binding name while calling my function `MoveIt`?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why the binding composite part name is needed but you can get it like this:

```
var binding = ctx.action.GetBindingForControl(ctx.control);
Debug.log(binding.value.name);
```

Or in one line:

```
var compositePart = ctx.action.GetBindingForControl(ctx.control).Value.name
```